# Парсинг данных из TableRow Android

Tags: java, android

Имеется `TableLayout` который содержит несколько `TableRow`, которые создаются программно.

`TableRow` содержит несколько `TextView` с текстом.

По нажатию на конкретный `TableRow` нужно запарсить все данные из всех `TextView` внутри этого `TableRow`.

Метод `onClick` уже висит на каждом `TableRow`, и у каждого уникальный `ID`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//...
tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
      TableRow t = (TableRow) view;
      TextView firstTextView = (TextView) t.getChildAt(0);
      TextView secondTextView = (TextView) t.getChildAt(1);
      String firstText = firstTextView.getText().toString();
      String secondText = secondTextView.getText().toString();
   }
});
//...
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)